# how not to get out of array boundaries

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array and by looping I compare cell with a cell near it. I get the 'out of range' exception,
How can I fix  it ?

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {                               
            if ((++array[i] == array[i+1])) {                    
                alert("yes");
            }
            else {
                alert("no");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What should the last element of the array be compared to? It fails on the last iteration because `i+1` results in a number that does not correspond to an array index.

Comment: The final compare is between the last element and the one before it.

Comment: In that case the two existing answers should be correct.

Comment: Are you intending to increase the value of each item in the array as well as compare nth with nth+1?

Answer (score 2):

Run your loop from `for (var i=0; i<array.length -1; i++)` instead (because you compare against `array[i+1]`)

Comment: @Damkulul : You can't have an out of bound error with this. Check again that you are testing ( i < array.length - 1 )  every time you need to access (i+1)th item.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you had in mind but using ++ outside of a for loop is never a good idea as it can be confusing. Use another variable to point to another item in the array while looping  together with a bounds checker is easier to debug and keeps loop simple.

```
//displays 01010
        //1=2(0),2=2(1),2=4(0),4=4(1),4=5(0)
        var ptr = 0;
        var items = new Array (1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5);
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            ptr++
            if(ptr >= items.length)break;
            if (items[i] == items[ptr]) {
                console.log(1);

            }
            else {
                console.log(0);
            }
        }

        //or
        //displays 10001 as each value is increased then compared
        //2=2(1),3=2(0),3=4(0),5=4(0),5=5(1)
        ptr = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            ptr++
            if (ptr >= items.length) break;
            if (++items[i] == items[ptr]) {
                console.log(1);
            }
            else {
                console.log(0);
            }
        }
```